# JBPM 5.4 human task service - BaseHornetQTaskServer and Process Engine Communication

Tags: jboss7.x, jbpm, hornetq

I have  registered ***AsyncHornetQHTWorkItemHandler*** with  ***KnowledgeRuntime***

```
AsyncHornetQTaskClient asyncHornetQTaskClient=new AsyncHornetQTaskClient("Async-Task-ProcEngine-Client");
        AsyncHornetQHTWorkItemHandler asyncHornetQHTWorkItemHandler = new AsyncHornetQHTWorkItemHandler(asyncHornetQTaskClient,knowledgeSession, OnErrorAction.RETHROW);
        asyncHornetQHTWorkItemHandler.setPort(5445);
        asyncHornetQHTWorkItemHandler.setIpAddress("localhost");
        logger.debug("Asycnhronous work-item-handler connecting....");
        asyncHornetQHTWorkItemHandler.connect();
        logger.debug("Asycnhronous work-item-handler connected.");
        knowledgeSession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task", asyncHornetQHTWorkItemHandler);
```

BaseHornetQTaskServer is configured to use the *standalone* HornetQ server running @ port 5445

```
public CustomHornetQTaskServer(TaskService service, String host, int port) {
        super(new HornetQTaskServerHandler(service, SystemEventListenerFactory.getSystemEventListener()), host, port, true);
}
```

Human Tasks are created successfully in Task database when a process instance is created.

I am using **AsyncHornetQTaskClient** (wrapped with *SyncTaskServiceWrapper*) from my web application to act (complete,skip, etc) on the Tasks.

```
TaskService  client = new SyncTaskServiceWrapper(new AsyncHornetQTaskClient("Async-Task-Client"));
        client.connect("127.0.0.1", 5445);
        return client;
```

The process engine is hosted in a separate VM to run as a **daemon/background service**.
Human-task service is embedded in my web-application hosted in Jboss 7.

How **KnowledgeRuntime.WorkItemManager** in the daemon service will get the event that work-item has completed ?

Should I explicity call **KnowledgeRuntime.getWorkItemManager().completeWorkItem**  ?

*Environment* : JBPM 5.4.0.Final, HornetQ 2.2.14.Final, Jboss 7

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am also interested in this topic.

Comment: AsyncGenericHTWorkItemHandler.TaskCompletedHandler will be doing this action "completWorkItem" for us. We don't have to explicitly call to complet workitem. To reduce the complexity, I have re-designed my application to use LocalTaskService.